# Open file from specific disk

Tags: python, django, filesystems

What I want to achieve is a bit complicated to explain, so I hope I'll be clear enough !

I'm starting to write a Django application for my company. It is installed on a local server which has access to some disks, that the users have access to also.

I want to be able to list some files on these disks and when a user clicks on one through the web interface, it opens it on his machine. But I don't want to download it on the user's machine, I want the user machine to open the file at its real location.

How can I achieve that ? And please let me know if I'm not being clear enough, it's really important that I can have this functionnality on my application.

Comment: Has every user mounted the same disks at the exact same mount-points?

Comment: Yes, the only thing is that the server is linux and the users are windows. But for every user it is the same so I can easily translate the path from the server to the windows path

Comment: I'm not sure if you can. I guess it would be a big security issue if browsers could open applications / files locally.

Comment: Yes I know it would be a big security issue but only if it was a distant server. Here everything is local. Both the server and the users have access to the file system anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `file://` protocol instead of `http://` in your links.

Comment: I didn't use http:// in my link, just the path to the file. I can manage to download a specific file on the user's computer. But I want to open the file at its correct location not create a copy.